# How to set up a Livestream from SJ4000 Wifi?

Tags: streaming, action-cam

I own a SJ4000 action cam with WIFI function. The latter allows it to connect the camera to my phone.

I would like to livestream a sports event. Is it somehow possible to stream the video from my phone? If it is easier to set up with a laptop, this would also be an option.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This link may be useful, it explains accessing SJCAM RTSP stream: http://how-i-did-that.blogspot.com/2014/11/reverse-engineering-sjcam4000-wifi-kind.html

Answer (score 4):

You have two choices...

- The wireless way:

  SJ4000 WiFi has a built-in RTSP streaming server, supporting *one client at a time* with a **limited resolution at 640x360**.

  This can be viewed locally by connecting your phone or laptop to the camera's access point, start a RTSP+H.264-capable media player (e.g. VLC Media Player), and instruct it to open following URL:

  ```
  rtsp://192.168.1.254/sjcam.mov
  ```

  However, if you would like to allow multiple people to watch the stream, you would need to install a live streaming software (that supports RTSP video source) on your phone or laptop.

  - VLC Media Player (at least the desktop version) can do a self-hosted live streaming in this scenario, but is awkward to set up.
  - [Open Broadcaster Studio](https://obsproject.com/) is known to [support this configuration](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/how-to-add-rtsp-ip-cam-video-source.43295/) as well as broadcasting into services like YouTube, Twitch, or Dailymotion.
- The wired way:

  SJ4000 WiFi is capable of acting as a USB webcam with **HD-ready 1280x720 resolution**.

  Once the camera's USB port is connected to laptop or OTG-capable Android phone, choose "PCCamera" mode on camera's screen; and you can view the stream locally with *any* webcam application.

  As you are going to re-broadcast the stream, *any* live streaming software should work (anything ranging from Google Hangouts, LINE, Facebook Live, Youtube app, to specialized ones like Open Broadcaster mentioned above).

Caveat:

As far as I have tested with my firmware version, **the camera does not provide audio streaming** in both RTSP and USB webcam mode. Since you are broadcasting sport event, you would have to insert live audio on-field in the live streaming software (optionally, with proper A/V delay compensation). Which in this case, the *wired way is recommended*, as there are more choices on software you can use.

If you are not particularly picky with the 0.6+ sec A/V desync, using *wired mode* with video chat applications mentioned above should suffice; they will pick audio from laptop/phone's microphone. However, if you need A/V delay compensation, use Open Broadcaster Studio or other specialized live streaming software of similar ability instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can also use [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/download) as an alternative, just follow [this guide](http://selimatmaca.com/index.php/live-streaming/138-encoder-software).

Answer (score 0):

After lots of unsuccessful attempts to connect different players on my laptop to rtsp://192.168.1.254/sjcam.mov I decided to make a bit of debugging with a packet sniffer to find out what occurs when SJCAM Zone Android app talks to the camera.

As a result I discovered that in the case of my camera the correct URL for VLC stream player is:
`http://192.168.1.254:8192`.
Seems that it's using a technique called HLS (HTTP Live Streaming).

My SJCam4000 Wifi is v1.7.